# SkiaSharp: How to draw to .net Graphics

Tags: .net, winforms, skiasharp

I need to read a SVG file and render it to the screen in my .net Windows Form application.
I found the SkiaSharp assemblies to be able to handle SVG files, but I didn't find a relation between SkiSharp classes and the Windows world.

How can I render a SkiaSharp object (either a SKPicture, SKCanvas or whatever is suitable) to a .net Forms Graphics object or better to a System.Drawing.Image?

If this is not possible, should I render into a PNG file and read it back? Or is there another more suitable assembly for my requirements?

Comment: You can use a WebBrowser Control to render SVGs. You won't need to add a third-party library in this case. Unless you need it for something else, I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that's not my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Now I've found a way to do it:

```
SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
svg.Load("Graphics.svg");
SKBitmap bitmap = new SKBitmap(100, 100); // 100x100 target size
var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Encode(stream, SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Then I have it in image and can draw that to my screen.

Comment: SKBitmap.Encode requires first param to be a SKWStream.  However there is no way to cast MemoryStream to SKWStream.   We cant use SKWStream instead, because Seek doesn't exist in SKWStream, only MemoryStream.